# After installing plugins, changes don't appear

Tags: plugins, network-admin

I installed a plugin by going to

```
my sites --> network admin --> plugins
```

and installing it from there. But the plugins don't show up. Would anyone know why they don't show up?

Also, the reason I had to go through

```
my sites --> network admin --> plugins
```

was because for some reason when I moused over the plugins in the dashboard, there was no option to add a new plugin.

Thanks!

Comment: What changes are you talking about?

Comment: @s_ha_dum for example I installed the social media feather plugin. Then I activated the plugin, but I don't see the social buttons on the blog posts. Here is a sample hello world page: http://graphicrevolutions.com/blog/blog/2014/03/21/hello-world/

Comment: Have you contacted the plugin developer?

Comment: @s_ha_dum of course, no :) This plugin works for me on other Wordpress accounts. So there is nothing wrong with the plugin. The problem, I think, is because of how I had to install the plugin by clicking on my sites --> network admin --> plugins. I am suspecting the issue is with that.

Comment: The plugin may not be "Multisite" friendly. Either way the first step seems to be to ask the developer.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I see. So since this account has many sites which use the same Wordpress setup, not all plugins may work the same, right? Would you know of any multi-site social media plugin?  Thanks!

Comment: I use very few plugins. The Social media plugin I do use I wrote, and is not released.

Comment: Did you installed your wordpress on Dreamhost?
How did you installed you wordpress?
Are you sure you logged in to the admin area with an admin user that have privilege to add plugins?